# Updating array data to a CSV file in php

Tags: php, csv

I want to load csv file data to extract the urls from CSV and check for the title tag for all the urls and update the urls with corresponding title tags in a new csv. But while I try to add data to the csv all the urls are getting listed but only the title of the last url is displayed in the CSV. I  have tried different ways to overcome this problem but unable to do so.

Here is my code:

```
  <?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', '300'); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
ini_set('max_execution_time', '0');

include('simple_html_dom.php');

// if (isset($_POST['resurl'])) {
//     $url = $_POST['resurl'];


if (($csv_file = fopen("old.csv", "r", 'a')) !== FALSE) {

    $arraydata = array();
    while (($read_data = fgetcsv($csv_file, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $column_count = count($read_data);

        for ($c = 0; $c < $column_count; $c++) {

            array_push($arraydata, $read_data[$c]);
        }
    }


    fclose($csv_file);
}
$title = [];

foreach ($arraydata as $ad) {
    $ard = [];
    $ard = $ad;
    $html = file_get_html($ard);

    if ($html) {
        $title = $html->find('title', 0)->plaintext;
        // echo '<pre>';
        // print_r($title);


    }
}


$ncsv = fopen("updated.csv", "a");
$head = "Url,Title";

fwrite($ncsv, "\n" . $head);

foreach ($arraydata as $value) {
    // $ar[]=$value;
    $csvdata = "$value,$title";
    fwrite($ncsv, "\n" . $csvdata);
}

fclose($ncsv);
```

Comment: You overwrite the value each time - `title[] = $html->find(` with the `[]` this adds the item to the array.

Comment: @NigelRen Its giving me array to string conversion error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it finally.

Here is the updated code:

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', '300'); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
ini_set('max_execution_time', '0');

include('simple_html_dom.php');

// if (isset($_POST['resurl'])) {
//     $url = $_POST['resurl'];


if (($csv_file = fopen("ntsurl.csv", "r", 'a')) !== FALSE) {

    $arraydata = array();
    while (($read_data = fgetcsv($csv_file, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $column_count = count($read_data);

        for ($c = 0; $c < $column_count; $c++) {

            array_push($arraydata, $read_data[$c]);
        }
    }


    fclose($csv_file);
}


// print_r($arraydata);
$title=[];
$ncsv=fopen("ntsnew.csv","a");
  $head="Website Url,title";
      fwrite($ncsv,"\n".$head);

foreach($arraydata as $ad)
{
       $ard = [];
    $ard = $ad;
    $html = file_get_html($ard);

    if ($html) {
        $title = $html->find('title', 0)->plaintext;
         echo '<pre>';
        print_r($title);


    $csvdata="$ard,$title ";
        fwrite($ncsv,"\n".$csvdata);

 
}

    }
// fclose($ncsv);
```

Comment: What is the point of `$ard`, especially setting it to `[]` and then `$ad`, in my answer I'd removed these as they are pointless.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the code so that you write the CSV file as you read the HTML pages.  This saves having another loop and an extra array of titles.

I've also changed it to use `fputcsv` to write the data out as it sorts ot things like escaping values etc.

```
// Open file, using w to clear the old file down
$ncsv = fopen('updated.csv', 'w');
$head = 'Url,Title';

fwrite($ncsv, "Url,Title" . PHP_EOL . $head);
foreach ($arraydata as $ad) {
    $html = file_get_html($ad);

    // Fetch title, or set to blank if html is not loaded
    if ($html) {
        $title = $html->find('title', 0)->plaintext;
    } else {
        $title = '';
    }
    // Write record out
    fputcsv($ncsv, [$value, $title]);
}

fclose($ncsv);
```

Comment: Thankyou I have tried to combine yours and mine code and was able to solve. I have posted the solution